Want to find an English vocabulary learning app
I want to find an English vocabulary learning app for an intermediary English user (~IELTS 5.5-6.0)--i know that there are plenty of such apps, such as Duolingo. The problem is, I want to find an app that allows users to add their own words. (The point is that, if learners encounter a word in their daily lives, they can add the word to the learning app, so that they can relate the language they learn to what they usually use).
Any recommendations?

You are better off just reading and looking up words you don't know. Individual words out of context are very hard to "learn". Just make an excel sheet. Why do you need an app? – I would spend time on my computer or on paper for this, not on a smartphone.

@Lambie the app can provide context, like sample sentences and illustrations. The app can also be cross-platform, supporting smartphones, tablets and desktop alike.

It's better to read texts like articles or books and as you come across new words look them up. Just seeing them in a single sentence is not the best way.

Sure, I just want to find the app. I am not saying it is the "best" way.
